# Command to replace string in one file with content of another file

Tags: sed, pipe, sh, cat

The file /var/cpanel/mainip contains the main IP of my server and nothing else.
The file /etc/csf/csf.blocklists contains a list of firewall blocklists, and part of the file contains a line with an example IP address 1.2.3.4

Normally when installing CSF firewall software on a new server, I will manually replace the example IP address with the server's main IP address. This is required to successfully fetch firewall blocklists from some providers.
To simplify the setup process, I want a command that will replace the example IP address 1.2.3.4 with my main server IP so I don't have to manually do it.

I've tried a sed command, I guess I'm close to the correct command but not quite there yet. Please can you help?

```
sed -i '/1.2.3.4/ { r /etc/csf/csf.blocklists }' /var/cpanel/mainip
```

This code is not right because it outputs an error:

sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'

When successful, it should replace 1.2.3.4 with the actual server IP address.

Comment: Insert newline before `}` or remove the useless `{` and `}`.

Comment: The `a`,`i`,`c`,`r`,`R`,`w` and `W` commands all demand to end in a newline. As your address `/1.2.3.4/` is only followed by single command i.e. `r file`, there is no need to surround it by parens. If there were a second command attached to the same address, the parens would be needed but two strings of commands would also be needed e.g. if the dummy address line was to be deleted too `sed -e '/1.2.3.4/{r file' -e 'd}' file`.

Comment: I think `sed -i '/1.2.3.4/ { r /etc/csf/csf.blocklists ; }' /var/cpanel/mainip` might also work. note the `;` before the closing `}`. But I like Mihir solution below best. I think your modified file will still contain `1.2.3.4`.Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i "s/1\.2\.3\.4/$(</var/cpanel/mainip)/"  /etc/csf/csf.blocklists
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to specify

`sed -i '/1.2.3.4/r /etc/csf/csf.blocklists' /var/cpanel/mainip`

In fact even the space is optional ; following will work too

`sed -i '/1.2.3.4/r/etc/csf/csf.blocklists' /var/cpanel/mainip`

You are simply specifying the pattern `/1.2.3.4/` and a command after that
The command could be `r` for read, `w` for write, `d` for delete and a few others
An example of `d` to delete the entry would be

`sed -i '/1.2.3.4/d' /var/cpanel/mainip`